# Proof-Verification: $ \int_a^b \left(\frac{b-x}{b-a}\right)^{2018}f(x)\,{\rm d}x \leq \frac{1}{2019}\int_a^b f(x)\,{\rm d}x$

Tags: proof-verification, integral-inequality

## Problem

Let $f(x)$ be continuous and increasing over $[a,b]$. Prove
$$\displaystyle \int_a^b \left(\frac{b-x}{b-a}\right)^{2018}f(x){\rm d}x \leq \frac{1}{2019}\int_a^b f(x){\rm d}x.$$

## Proof

By the second mean value theorem for integrals ，$\exists \xi \in [a,b]$ such that
\begin{align*}
&\int_a^b \left[\left(\frac{b-x}{b-a}\right)^{2018}-\frac{1}{2019}\right]f(x){\rm d}x\\
=&f(a)\int_a^\xi \left[\left(\frac{b-x}{b-a}\right)^{2018}-\frac{1}{2019}\right]{\rm d}x+f(b)\int_\xi^b \left[\left(\frac{b-x}{b-a}\right)^{2018}-\frac{1}{2019}\right]{\rm d}x\\
=&f(a)\int_a^b \left[\left(\frac{b-x}{b-a}\right)^{2018}-\frac{1}{2019}\right]{\rm d}x+[f(b)-f(a)]\int_\xi^b \left[\left(\frac{b-x}{b-a}\right)^{2018}-\frac{1}{2019}\right]{\rm d}x\\
=&f(a)\cdot 0+[f(b)-f(a)]\int_\xi^b \left[\left(\frac{b-x}{b-a}\right)^{2018}-\frac{1}{2019}\right]{\rm d}x\\
=&\frac{1}{2019}\cdot (b-\xi)\cdot [f(b)-f(a)]\cdot \left[\left(\frac{b-\xi}{{b-a}}\right)^{2018}-1\right]\\
\leq &0,
\end{align*}
which implies what we want.

**HOPE TO SEE OTHER PROOFS. THANKS.**

Comment: Sorry, a typo. Corrected.

Comment: Yes, it's right and you can use [Chebyshev's sum inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_sum_inequality).

Comment: Another way is to find a proper integration by substitution, and then try $\int_a^b f(x) dx=\frac{1}{2}(\int_a^b (f(x)+f(a+b-x))dx)$

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9687/guidelines-for-good-use-of-rm-latex-in-question-titles.